# Passing mysqli connection to a PHP function - out of synch

Tags: php, mysqli, arguments

I have a problem when performing mysql commands when I invoke a function in another file.  If I have the code in the same file, it works fine.  The code looks like:

authenticate:

```
{
    $conn = new mysqli($dbserver, "dbuser", "pass", $dbname);
    $sql = 'SELECT userId, salt, pwd, isAdmin FROM users where username = ?';
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->bind_result($userId, $salt, $storedPwd, $isAdmin);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Now, if I call a function, immediately after fetch, it fails on the bind_param line.  I call it like this:

```
updateUserActivity ($conn, $tpcLang, 'LI', $userId);
```

the beginning of this function is:

```
function updateUserActivity ($conn, $lang, $activityType, $userId)
{
    // check that activity is valid
    $sql = 'SELECT activityType
            FROM activityType  
            WHERE activityType = ?';
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $activityType);
    $stmt->bind_result($activityTypeInDB);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($activityType == $activityTypeInDB){
        $success=1;
    } else {
       $success=0;
       $msg = $lang->get('UPDATE_USER_INVALID_ACTIVITY_ERROR_MSG') . " " . $activityType . " (" . $stmt->errno . "):  " . $stmt->error;
       error_log ($msg);
    }
    // continue on to add a row in the userActivity table
}
```

The error I get on the bind_param is:  invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt, and the DB error is:  Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this after your fetch.

```
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

or

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: The amount of times in my early coding days that I would get caught out by using an already set resource!

Comment: Thank you.  I've put a stmt->close() in there and it works.  I'm now in the process of ensuring all stmts are closed.